# How do I get FOR to work on a list but leaping through it according to another list and how to get it back to the start to keep counting like a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

So this is the chromatic_scale = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B']
I want to form major, minor and other scales based on this.
To form a major scale, for example, I need to leap through the chromatic scale like this: major = [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1] (in music, we say "tone, tone, semitone, tone, tone, tone, semitone" where tone means leaping 2 list items and semitone means leaping 1, thus the list)
A practical example: Starting from 'C', I should get ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'C'] (yes, it should loop back to 'C' at the end).

1 - I thought of doing it with FOR but how do I get FOR to work on a list (chromatic) but leaping through it according to another list (major)?

2 - And if I start from 'A', for instance, how to get it back to the beginning to keep counting?

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I managed to do it but I used WHILE instead of FOR.

```
chromatic = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B',
             'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B']


def major(tom):
    major_scale = [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]
    step = 0
    t = chromatic.index(tom)
    m = []
    while len(m) < 8:
        m.append(chromatic[t])
        if len(m) == 8:
            break
        t += major_scale[step]
        step += 1
    return m


x = major('D')
print(x)
```

Thank you everyone!